# ThreeJS page/scene transition

Tags: three.js

I am trying to figure out the concept on how this site (http://igoodi.eu/) do its transition between different objects. Like when you are in the homepage and try to scroll down, the scene rotates vertically (maybe 90degrees). I want to know on how to do this or maybe the concept behind this.

The thing is I want to implement a three faces/pages (Triangular Prism) in a website. And the transition will be like it would rotate horizontally and it will display the other face of the triangle.